# How do i handle MessageBoxes with Expensify WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, wp7test

I have a Windows phone 7.1 App, and I'm trying to implement som UI tests using Expensify's WP7Test framework and SpecFlow's Gherkin-feature. 
I'm having real trouble testing whether my application is started correctly when run for the first time, because i prompt the user with MessageBox'es about access for GPS and Internet before the main screen is shown.
Firstly this code was (rather crudely) in the "App" Class constructor - i tried moving it to the "OnNavigatedTo" method of the MainPage, same result.

```
 Trace:->Command timed out waiting for send              
 Trace:->Command timed out waiting for send              
 Trace:->Command timed out waiting for send              
 Trace:->Command timed out waiting for send              
 Trace:->Command timed out waiting for send              
 Trace:->Command timed out waiting for send              
 Trace:->Command timed out waiting for send              
 -> error:   App is not yet alive
```

It work's perfectly when i comment the messagebox'es out, but i really want to test them as well - my MainPage renders accordingly to the answers of those prompts!

I have tried a lot of diffrent Steps in the Scenario for starting the application:

```
Given my app is clean installed and running    /
Given my app is running within 20 seconds      /
Then my app is running                        /
```

Comment: Actually, i got around the startup problem by using pages instead of Messageboxes in this case - but i still would like to answer MessageBoxes using the WP7Test-client. I can't be the only one using MessageBoxes and UI testing on WP7 right?

Answer (score 1):

Because the test framework interacts with ui elements it has to use the ui thread - so I guess you messagebox is somehow blocking the ui message pump here.

Perhaps this case is caused here because this is your first page... but I'd need to do some testing to check.

One simple workaround could be to use the asynchronous message box methods for your functionality  - but this would require you to reorganise your page init functionality a little.

---

If this is a serious issue for you, please do log an issue and a sample test in github.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm guessing that's the same reason i can't get it to use the on screen keyboard?

I'm using the WP7Test framework for an exam project in software-testing and mobile applications, so an explanation is almost as good as a solution - and i doubt any issue i log would be resolved before my deadline on tuesday :p

Comment: No. The on screen keyboard is different. You can use that if you want to program touches to it. But by default the wp7test uses pgup then hardware keyboard emulation. Topic closed for me now. Stackoverflow comments aren't really intended for extended questions and conversations :)